# Merge temporally continuous records based on common id

Tags: r, date, array-merge

This is my data of time intervals

```
dates <- seq(from=as.Date("1980-01-01"), to=as.Date("1980-01-31"), by = 'day')

my_data <- 
  data.frame(from_date = c(dates[1], dates[15], dates[20], dates[30]),
             to_date = c(dates[14], dates[19], dates[22], dates[31]),
             id = c(1, 1, 2, 3))
```

Few of the observations are **continuous**, they end the day before the following starts.

```
my_data$is_continued <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE) 

my_data
   from_date    to_date id is_continued
1 1980-01-01 1980-01-14  1         TRUE
2 1980-01-15 1980-01-19  1         TRUE
3 1980-01-20 1980-01-22  2        FALSE
4 1980-01-30 1980-01-31  3        FALSE
```

Now I want to simplify my table. I want one observation instead of two (or more than two) when:

1. Observations are **continuous**
2. They share the same `id`

That is, I want this result

```
desired_result <- 
  data.frame(from_date = c(dates[1], dates[20], dates[30]),
             to_date = c(dates[19], dates[22], dates[31]),
             id = c(1, 2, 3))
```

What would be the best approach?

Comment: is `my_data[!duplicated(my_data[, c("id","is_continued")], fromLast = T), ]` what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

By looping:

```
groupContinous <- function(df) {

  df <- df[order(df$from_date),]

  df$continuing <- c(FALSE, c(df$from_date[2:nrow(df)] - df$to_date[1:(nrow(df))-1] == 1))

  membership <- 1
  for (i in 2:nrow(df)) {
    if (df$continuing[i] == TRUE) {
      membership <- c(membership, max(membership)) 
    } else {
      membership <- c(membership, max(membership)+1)
    }
  }
  df$membership <- membership

  require(dplyr)
  df_simp <- 
    df %>%
    dplyr::group_by(id, membership) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(from_date = min(from_date),
                     to_date = max(to_date))
  df_simp$membership <- NULL

  return(as.data.frame(df_simp))
}
```